# Javascript onclick dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, drop-down-menu

I'm struggling with this javascript at the moment.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var visible = false;
        var body = false;

        $("body").mouseup(function () {
            if (visible) {
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow');
                visible = false;
                $(this).removeClass("clicked-background");
                body = true;
            }
        });

        $("ul.topnav li a").click(function () { //When trigger is clicked...
            var menu = $(this).parent().find('ul.subnav');

            if (!visible && !body) {
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show();
                visible = true;
                $(this).addClass("clicked-background");
            }
            // else if (visible) 
            //{
            //   $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow');
            //   visible = false;
            //   $(this).removeClass("clicked-background");
            // }

            body = false;
        });

    });
```

I wanted to add the feature, so if you clicked outside the menu/navigation the dropdown would hide.
The current problem with this code is, that if you click the menu and then click outside the menu - you have to double click the menu again to get it showen. This is caused by the body variable is set too 'True' ofc.

I made the body variable trying to fix the problem if you clicked the menu - and then clicked the same link again. The menu would first open correctly, and then close and open again.
Soo main problem is. My navigation open -> closes -> open

Comment: plz add jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use global variables. Check if the actual element is visible by checking

```
.is(':visible');
```

You can use that on the various selectors you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use onmouseout of the 'now visible' menu as the event of choice..

I dont think that running events off of the body tag is the good way to go.

the flow should be..

```
click (menu button or link)
show menu
set onmouseout for button and menu on click
onmouseout, remove onmouseout events
```